# How to receive a Broadcast receiver during install and uninstall the application?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get notified when the app is downloaded and installed from Google Play. Is there any way to receive the broadcast receiver within the same application. Is there any possibility to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application cannot be notified of itself being installed/uninstalled

Comment: This is correct. I've tried to do this, but in the end it was just a big waste of time.

Comment: Also, With Android 3.1+ devices the app will not receive any broadcast unless the user opens the app once.